# Detoured function not being called

Tags: c++, detours

I'm using visual studio 2003 with CDetour.
This time I cannot give a SSCE so this is what I've done:

```
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;

CDetour CreateDevice_Det;
IDirect3D9* Direct3DCreate9_Hook( UINT SDKVersion )
{
        MessageBox( GetForegroundWindow(), "Direct9 Create Hooked", "dForce.dll", MB_OK );
        d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
        return d3d;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD reason,LPVOID reserved)
{
    switch(reason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            HMODULE hd3d = GetModuleHandle( "d3d9.dll" );
            if( hd3d == 0 )
            {
                MessageBox( GetForegroundWindow(), "d3d9.dll still not loaded", "dForce.dll", MB_ICONSTOP );
                return FALSE;
            }
            DWORD lpAddr = (DWORD)GetProcAddress( hd3d, "Direct3DCreate9" );
            if( lpAddr == 0 )
            {
                MessageBox( GetForegroundWindow(), "could not find valid d3d9.dll create device address", "dForce.dll", MB_ICONSTOP );
                return FALSE;
            }
            CreateDevice_Det.Detour( (LPBYTE)lpAddr, (LPBYTE)Direct3DCreate9_Hook );
            CString strDetoured;
            strDetoured.Format( "CreateDevice Hooked! Address: %x", (LPVOID)lpAddr );
            MessageBox( GetForegroundWindow(), strDetoured, "dFoce.dll", MB_ICONINFORMATION );
        }break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I have hooked another functions such as `LoadLibrary` (from kernel32.dll) with success the same way, this dll is of course loaded before `Direct3DCreate9` on the main program, I have also tried this on a console wi32 program but my hooked function is still not called. Am I missing something?

## edited

Apparently CDetour is not related to MS Detours at all (found it googling for ms detours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you `CreateDevice_Det.Detour( ...)` you must apply the detour, it's not auto. 
`CreateDevice_Det.Apply()`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see detourTransactionBegin(), DetourUpdateThread() and DetourTransactioncommit() calls here. [API Hooking with MS Detours](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours) have a good explaination.

Comment: I think that's because he's using CDetours, which from what I found googling it is not related to MS Detours.

Comment: well the guy  says MSDetours (aka CDetour)

Comment: Yes, but all when I browsed some code on the web I found from CDetours it didn't look like Detours at all. The hooking was done manually, using various methods like 0xe9 jmp and so on, without calling the MS Detour methods. So it didn't appear to be a wrapper either. And have you ever heard MS Detours being called CDetour?

Comment: The source code I found is [here](http://code.google.com/p/sourceop/source/browse/trunk).

Comment: Nope, Why would MSDetour be called as CDetour? After all its MS's stuff. This certainly looks like an approach what detour actually does. Though i didn't spent much but it seems to generate the Detour and trampoline functions which MSDetours2.x used to do.